# Gradle multi-project build: how to specify different build files?

Tags: gradle, multi-project, build-script

Gradle multi-project build: how to set different build files? e.g.

```
/foo/bar/build-hello.gradle
/foo/bar/build-world.gradle

settings.gradle

include 'hello'
project(':hello').projectDir = new File('/foo/bar')
project(':hello').buildFile = new File('/foo/bar/build-hello.gradle')

include 'world'
project(':world').projectDir = new File('/foo/bar')
project(':world').buildFile = new File('/foo/bar/build-world.gradle')
```

Error: can not set readOnly property buildFile.

How to specify a different build file other than the default build.gradle?

EDIT:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:projectDir

```
File projectDir (read-only)
The directory containing the project build file.
```

projectDir is also readOnly. But no error in setting its value. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `settings.gradle` file operates on a [`Settings`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html) object, whose `project()` method returns [`ProjectDescriptor`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/ProjectDescriptor.html) instances, because the `Project` instances are not created at this point of the Gradle build.

The read-only `buildFile` property of the `ProjectDescriptor` instances is created from the two writable properties `projectDir` and `buildFileName`:

```
include 'hello'
project(':hello').projectDir = new File('/foo/bar')
project(':hello').buildFileName = 'build-hello.gradle'

include 'world'
project(':world').projectDir = new File('/foo/bar')
project(':world').buildFileName = 'build-world.gradle'
```